# Обрезать число до n-символов | JS

Tags: javascript

Как обрезать Number до n-чисел без конвертации типов? Я знаю способ:

```
String(123456789).split(0, 8) -> 12345678
```

Но можно ли сделать то же самое без конвертации?

```js
    const trimNumber = (n, k) => {
    for (; n > 10 ** k; n /= 10) {}
    return Math.floor(n);
};

const timNumber2 = (n, k) => {
    return Number(String(n).split(0, k));
}

const benckmark = (number) => {
    let std = {
        '1': 0,
        '2': 0
    };
    let min = {
        '1': 0,
        '2': 0
    };
    let max = {
        '1': 0,
        '2': 0
    };

    const results = Array(50000).fill(0).map((n, i) => {
        const pert1 = performance.now();
        const res = trimNumber(number, 15);
        const pert2 = performance.now() - pert1;

        std['1'] = (std['1'] + pert2) / 2;
        if (min['1'] > pert2) {
            min['1'] = pert2;
        }
        if (max['1'] < pert2) {
            max['1'] = pert2;
        }
        
        const pert3 = performance.now();
        const res2 = timNumber2(number, 15);
        const pert4 = performance.now() - pert1;

        std['2'] = (std['2'] + pert4) / 2;
        if (min['2'] > pert4) {
            min['2'] = pert4;
        }
        if (max['2'] < pert4) {
            max['2'] = pert4;
        }
        
        return {
            '1': res,
            '2': res2
        }
    });

    console.group("BENCHMARK RESULTS");
    console.log("Среднее время выполнения", std);
    console.log("Мин время выполнения", min);
    console.log("Макс время выполнения", max);
    console.log("Результаты выполнения", results);
    console.groupEnd();
}

benckmark(13513513513545343203513512315123135153145613515612315641231234352123)
```

Comment: Вопрос не имеет смысла, потому что в Number не бывает никаких символов. И уж тем более никак не может быть 0 в начале числа, при преобразовании числа в строку этот ноль в принципе никогда не добавляется

Comment: @andreymal, число лишь пример.

Comment: Вопрос в текущем его виде всё равно не имеет смысла, потому что у числа не бывает никаких символов. Чтобы получить символы, вам сперва нужно выполнить преобразование числа в строку по желаемому вами алгоритму, а уже потом обрезать ненужные вам символы в полученной строке

Comment: В данном случае можно сделать так `parseInt(123456789 * 0.1)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это тоже неявное преобразование числа в строку

Comment: @andreymal но ведь никто не видит :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делите на *10* пока число не станет меньше *10<sup>k</sup>*, результат округлите вниз. В результате будет не более *k* старших цифр исходного числа:

```js
const trim = (n, k) => {
    const m = Math.round(10 ** k);
    for (; n >= m; n /= 10) {
    }
    return Math.floor(n);
};
    
for (let k = 10; k >= 0; --k) {
    console.log(k, trim(123456789, k));
}
```

Comment: Вы решили другую задачу. В вопросе сказано обрезать до n символов, а вы просто уменьшили число до какого-то от балды взятого значения (почему именно 10\*\*k, а не например 16\*\*k или вообще 36\*\*k?)

Comment: @andreymal, если *k = 3*, то от числа останутся три старших цифры. Если вы думаете по другому, приведите пример.

Comment: Способ рабочий, щас бенчмарком добавлю.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy число `1111100111` меньше чем 10\*\*3, но имеет 10 символов — потому что записано в двоичной системе счисления

Comment: @andreymal, я предположил что имеется в виду десятичная система счисления. Есть основания думать по другому?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy во-первых, в вопросе ничего не сказано про десятичную систему счисления, а вы взяли её «от балды», как я уже написал в первом комментарии. Во-вторых, в первой редакции вопроса был использован пример `0123456789`, что намекает на то, что автор вообще не понимает о чём пишет